# Automatic css closing bracket in Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, sublimetext3

When creating a new CSS rule, I would like the closing bracket to be placed automatically right under the class name, so as a result, later, it would stay on the same line as the last property: value pair:

```
.rule {
display: block;
clor: #000; }
```

```
.rule {
}   /* It should look like this when pressing enter after 
    the opening bracket with the cursor before the closing bracket (obviously). */
```

I have tried `“auto_match_enabled”: false` but this simply disables the closing bracket, so I need to add it manually.

I have installed PackageResourceViewer and looked into CSS.sublime-syntax and css_completions.py but could not find any corresponding setting or code. I have also found nothing in the default snippets.

**EDIT**
How could I get below result?

```
.rule {
  | }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine what's happening in response to a key press, open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console` or the associated key, and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` to turn on command logging, then take the action.

In doing this, you can see that in a situation like this:

```css
.rule {|}
```

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the command that triggers is:

```
command: run_macro_file {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}
```

From this you can determine that the key is bound to `run_macro_file`, and that the macro is what's taking this action. If you look in the default key bindings, the key binding is:

```json
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

That is, if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while `auto_indent` is turned on, the selection is empty, and the cursor is sitting in the middle of two braces `{}`, run the macro, which takes the step of inserting multiple lines.

Simplistically, you can thus stop this from happening by turning off `auto_indent`. However that's not a viable solution generally speaking, so you would need to create a key binding in your `User` package that, in the same situation doesn't do this and instead just does what `enter` would do:

```json
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" },
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

This is the same binding as above, but now the `command` just inserts a single line, and it also constrains itself only to CSS files via the `source.css` match in the `selector`.

With this in place, the css looks like the following when you press the key in this situation:

```
.rule{
|}
```

---

**EDIT**

The Text in the `characters` argument of the `insert` command can be set to any text that you'd like to type, so you could for example set it to `"\n\t"` or `"\n  "` (newline and two spaces) in order to have a bit of indentation on the new line.

In order to achieve a result like the following, a slightly different command is required:

```
.rule {
  | }
```

Here there is space before and after the cursor, which precludes the use of the `insert` command since the cursor always ends up after the last character inserted.

One way to to do this would be to create a macro similar to what already happens for the default binding of this key, but another way would be the `insert_snippet` command. This can insert a snippet file but it also takes an argument of `contents` that tells it the snippet content directly.

With that in mind, the above key binding could be expressed as:

```json
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\t"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" },
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

`insert_snippet` expands out the snippet text (including any fields, if any are provided) and then places the cursor at `$0`, which defaults to the end of the inserted content if not provided.

Inserting a `\t` character inserts a tab, which will be a physical tab character unless `translate_tabs_to_spaces` is turned on, in which case the insertion will replace the `\t` with the same number of spaces as `tab_size` is currently set to.

You could of course also use a specific amount of space characters instead, if that is desired.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my edited original question. How would I make the cursor be indented and how would I keep the space between the closing bracket and the cursor automatically? I've tried to fiddle with the key bindings you kindly posted here but I didn't achieve anything.

Comment: @yendrrek is the amount of space before and after the cursor based on the tab size? Or maybe before is the tab size and after is always the same (e.g. 2)?

Comment: Before and after the cursor space is the same, 2 precisely.  When I press TAB it moves by 2. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @yendrrek I've edited the answer to extend it to this particular use case.

Comment: You are a real godsend.